# Strategy to group together logically related procedures

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I've got a list of logically related external procedures, written in the same source file, and I'd like to share them among all the programs.
What's the best strategy to do that? Considering in the future I'd like to expand this "library".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect definition of a [Service Program](https://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/Service_Program).

Comment: Should I include it using BNDSRVPGM or creating a bind directory?

Comment: IMO, using a binding directory is easier ... that way you can add service programs to the list of commonly used ones without having to make other changes. Plus you can reference the binding directory in your source.